# How to use remix-flat-routes on Windows?

Tags: remix.run

I would like to apply https://github.com/kiliman/remix-flat-routes hybrid convention to my remix.run application to improve maintainability and readability of my code base.

Unfortunately my routes consist of catalog names based on URL parameters e.g. `/foo/$bar/acme`, which in `remix-flat-routes` convention turns into catalogs named `foo+`, `:bar` and `acme+` - all nested in each other. The `:` sign is prohibited on Windows, so I cannot use such approach.

Is there a way to configure parametrised catalog names or is there another solution to make it work on Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be as simple as using `$` instead of prohibited `:` sign